# How to modify a property in a Javascript class from within a method of that class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, oop

I'm creating a React app in which I have a class called `FirebaseManager`. After logging in with Google, we retrieve an object with all the info we need from the user from Firebase. I want to store this info in an object of the class `User`, to serve it locally in the UI. For this purpose I created a property `currentUser` in `FirebaseManager` in which I initialise an empty object of `User` and then update it with the method `updateUser`. Here is the code for them:

```
// Current logged in user
  currentUser = new User();

  // Update user
  updateUser(user, data) {
    user.name = data.user.displayName;
    user.email = data.user.email;
    user.picture = data.user.photoURL;
    user.uid = data.user.uid;
    console.log("User inside updateUser method: ", user, "Data: ", data)
  };
```

Now, I call `updateUser` right after logging in to Firebase with Google. I do this with the method `responseGoogle`:

```
// Logs in with Google
  responseGoogle = googleUser => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      unsubscribe();
      if (!this.isGoogleUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
        // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
        const credential = this.googleProvider.credential(googleUser.tokenId);
        // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then(data => {
            // We populate the currentUser object
            this.updateUser(this.currentUser, data)
            console.log("Current user from promise: ", this.currentUser);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        console.log("User already signed-in Firebase.");
      }
    });
  };
```

Within the promise `.then`, the `currentUser` property is modified, but whenever I try to import it from another file, it is empty and its new values haven't been populated. What I do to import it to another file is exporting an object of the class `FirebaseManager`:

```
let firebaseManager = new FirebaseManager();

export default firebaseManager;
```

Then I just import `firebaseManager` in the files I need it and I try to access the property `currentUser`, but `firebaseManager.currentUser` always returns an empty object of the class `User`.

All in all, and as a summary, what we want is being able to store the user info from Firebase in an `User` object and being able to export it to other modules in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that whenever I called the `firebaseManager` object, a new object of the class was created, thus, even if I changed the property `currentUser` in one object, this change wasn't replicated in the rest of objects.

What I did, instead, is the following:

1. Refactoring the class `FirebaseManager` and turn it into several objects.
2. Using this [firebase state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener#onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)) to populate an object of the class `User`.
3. I did this from the most general component of my app: `App`. I stored the active user in its state, and I passed it down to any children component that needs it.

As a side note, this functionality can be improved upon with [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), and we might implement this in the future.